# Basic questions about Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, rxjs, rxjs5

Im developing a small app with angular2 and I installed Rxjs 5.
In every tutorial there is a diffrent way to import the Rxjs libary.
The code to import in [angular2 web](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs) is not working; I mean that Websotrm doesn't recognize Observable or any of its functions (from,subscribe,...).

1. What do I need to do to fix that?
2. If I import everything from Rxjs, does the load of the website will be slower? (I won't have more then 2- classes)
3. (Webstorm question) How to I make webstorm to autocomplete the name of the functions with out pressing alt+space

Comment: Try scaffolding your app with `angular-cli`, and it will make `rxjs` available by default. You just need to import it into your component.

Comment: I got too much errors while using angular-cli. so I moved to the basic seed project angular team published. How does the angular cli does import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest RXJS distributions offer broken up modules to mitigate the gigantic filesize, à la Lodash. Importing `rxjs/Rx` (as another answer suggests) will get you the entirety of the library and isn't suggested.

Instead, import methods and operators individually:

- for core classes, import the class from its scoped module: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`
- for instance methods, use the instance scope in the "add" scope: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent'` (note there is no destructured object to import – the method is added automatically by the import)
- for operators, import from the `add/operator` scope: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'`

Importing an operator once makes it available to all instances, so it's recommended to gather all the parts you use in a single file and import that file wherever needed, I.E. by re-exporting the instances you use.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/flatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

export { Observable, BehaviorSubject };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This works in my projects: `import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";`
2. You only need to add `Rx.umd.min.js` from `rxjs/bundles`. It's about 170KB.
3. Try upgrading to WebStorm 2016.2. I am using that version and it works fine (provided you have the correct imports) Has better support for Angular 2 in general. See change notes.
   I virtually never use Ctrl+Space. Tip: Set the `Autopopup code completion` value (Settings, Editor, Code Completion) to a very low delay.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How and where do I add Rx.umd.min.js? And I have Webstrom 2016.2 and How can I change the delay of the code cmpletion? it is very slow.

Comment: Pay attention to import from rxjs/Rx, as it will import all the observable types and it's operators, which will sum up in compiled app space. The import statement for the observable and subject types is rxjs/[type] operators import statement are based on static and instance imports